# Android WebRTC - send YUV frames in NV12 format?

Tags: webrtc, webrtc-android

My project currently streams YUV 420P frames over WebRTC, using WebRTC's `JavaI420Buffer` class to wrap up the I420 format `ByteBuffer` that I obtain from an external camera source, and passing it in to my video source's capture observer.

Now however I want to support another camera feed which is giving me YUV NV12 format input. Is there no way of sending these frames directly over WebRTC, without first converting the NV12 format to 420 planar?

(Converting the `ByteBuffer` naively with the CPU (i.e. a couple of for-loops) is predictably giving me horrible results at 30 frames per second. And I'm not entirely sure if I need to follow this conversion route or not, hence this question.)

Comment: Did you find an answer to this?

Comment: @decades not really - in the end I rewrote the the NV12 to 420P conversion code in C++ using the JNI, I was surprised but this gave me good enough performance.

Comment: Hehe, same here :)

Comment: For modern devices even the Java representation is fast enough, but as always with Android, there are these damn old boxes :)